# Perl and Windows Win32 Credential Manager API

Tags: perl

I am not an advanced Perl or Windows developer.

My question, is it possible via ActivePerl 5.22 on Win64 to interface with the Win32 Credential Manager API/windows.security.credentials. I want to use the API to manage user credentials, by that view accounts, add accounts and delete accounts.

I found a PowerShell example that does exactly that but I cannot use powershell at work, also looking to understand the limitations of Perl when it comes to interacting wih Win32 API's.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: What do you mean by *"extract the generic password"*? I don't know of such a thing, and Google seems to agree with me. Perhaps you should elaborate further on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Borodin - generic paswords - Generic credentials are defined and authenticated by applications that manage authorization and security directly instead of delegating these tasks to the operating system. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380517(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with Win32 api calls through the CPAN module [WIn32::API](http://search.cpan.org/~acalpini/Win32-API-0.41/API.pm)